# How can I find what postgres table a particular OS datafile is associated with?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres 9.3 database which a query against pg_class reports total space used for a tablespace as 568G, which the corresponding files on the server report 685G.

Shouldn't all of the file bases appear in pg_class, or am I missing something.  For example, there are files named '103154174', '103154174.1' and so on to '.7'.  The 103154174 doesn't appear in pg_class.  (FWIW, this file has a timestamp of Jun 5 of this year).

Am I missing something?  Shouldn't that file, which is in the directory for the database I am working with, appear when I select pg_relation_filepath(c.oid) from pg_class, or can it be part of a different table that also incorporates differently named files?

Here is the query that I used to identify the server files:

```
SELECT pg_relation_filepath(c.oid) filepath,
       nspname, 
       relname, 
       relnamespace, 
       reltablespace, 
       (relpages * 8) / 1024 size_mb, 
       sum((relpages * 8) / 1024) over (partition by relnamespace) ns_total_size_mb,
       sum((relpages * 8) / 1024) over (partition by reltablespace) ts_total_size_mb,
       sum((relpages * 8) / 1024) over (partition by 'x') total_size_mb,
       sum((relpages * 8) / 1024) over (partition by 'x'order by relpages desc) running_total_size_mb
FROM pg_class c
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
```

edit:  Let me be clear.  I understand that pg_class does not contain entries for the files with .1, .2 etc extensions.  I am referring to files without the file name extensions (e.g., file name 103154174 referenced above).

Comment: `over (partition by 'x')` can be replace with `over ()` and `over (partition by 'x'order by relpages desc)` should probably be `over (order by c.oid)`

Answer (score 1):

The files ending with `.1`,  `.2` ... will **not** show up in pg_class. pg_class only lists each relation **once**, but each relation can consist of multiple files if it exceeds 1 GB

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html)

> When a table or index exceeds 1 GB, it is divided into gigabyte-sized segments. The first segment's file name is the same as the filenode; subsequent segments are named filenode.1, filenode.2, etc.

`pg_relation_filepath()` will only report the "base file", not the additional segments.

Comment: The file I was asking about is named '103154174' (i.e., didn't have the . extenders).  It's there on the server, but nowhere to be found in the database, as far as I can tell.